# Shortest code to read a file and then update it?

Tags: haskell, io

I need to read, modify and then update some files in the same function. The ideal solution (see below) could not work, it is wrong. The "worst" solution works.

```
-- Ex. "Pseudocode" - Doesn't work.
ideal = let pathFile = "C:\\TEMP\\Foo.txt" 
           in readFile pathFile >>= writeFile pathFile . (++ "!")

-- It works. 
worst = do
    let pathFile = "C:\\TEMP\\Foo.txt"
    h <- openFile pathFile ReadMode
    cs <- hGetContents h 
    (temp_Foo,temp_handle) <- openTempFile pathFile
    hPrint temp_handle $ cs ++ "!"
    hClose temp_handle
    removeFile pathFile
    renameFile temp_Foo pathFile
```

I would prefer to avoid "the simple but ugly workaround" suggested by Reid Burton in 2010:

```
doit file = do
    contents <- readFile file
    length contents `seq` (writeFile file $ process contents)
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Well, you can have a conduit/pipes solution. :)

Comment: @Sibi These libraries are huge. I think that requires a long time to be mastered. Also, I don't think to use a cannon to kill a mosquito.

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani you don't need a cannon to kill a mosquito – but nor do you need a supercomputer (by 70's standards) for making phone calls.

Comment: If you do `import qualified Data.Text.IO as T` you have strict text and `ideal` works fine `T.readFile pathFile >>= T.writeFile pathFile . (<> "!")`. The `text` package is the standard way of handling text.

Comment: @Michael Thank you, but I chose the example just for simplicity. I work with sets and maps and other much more complex structures.

Comment: I'm not sure how any answer to this question could apply to sets and maps.

Comment: @Michael It's true, but leftaroundabout's answer got me thinking and I clarified many things. So I defined this general function, and now all work: updateFile :: forall a. Show a => FilePath -> String -> a -> IO ()
updateFile pathDir nameFile content = do
    let pathFile = pathDir ++ nameFile
    (tempFile,ht) <- openTempFile pathDir nameFile
    hPrint ht content
    hClose ht
    removeFile pathFile 
    renameFile tempFile pathFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `ideal` is that it reads the string lazily, i.e. the file isn't fully in memory before you already try to open it again for writing.

This kind of lazyness is by now widely considered a bad idea<sup>†</sup> – if you really do need such read-as-you-go capabilities, then [conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit)/[pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes) is what you want.

In your example, you don't really need lazyness *at all* though, unless the file is too big to warrant having it in memory at once. So you can just use `readFile`, but need to make it strict: a manual way to do that would be

```
ideal = do
    fc <- readFile pathFile
    length fc `seq` writeFile pathFile (fc++ "!")
 where pathFile = "C:\\TEMP\\Foo.txt"
```

Here I've used `length` to ensure the string is really evaluated to the end. A nicer way of ensuring the same thing is with [`deepseq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.2.0/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html):

```
ideal = do
    fc <- readFile pathFile
    fc `deepseq` writeFile pathFile (fc++ "!")
```

...or, if you want it point-free,

```
ideal = readFile pathFile >>= (writeFile pathFile . (++ "!") $!!)
```

Note that the more modern variants of `readFile` with more efficient types than `String` – in particular, [`Data.Text.readFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text-IO.html#v:readFile) – don't need any of this, because they're strict out of the box. The following therefore just works, and is probably the best solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Prelude hiding (readFile, writeFile)
import Data.Text.IO
import Data.Monoid ((<>))

main :: IO ()
main = readFile pathFile >>= writeFile pathFile . (<> "!")
 where pathFile = "/tmp/foo.txt"
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>In the very early days of Haskell, all “interleaved IO” was actually based on lazyness, hence the old libraries were somewhat drowned with it.</sub>